Conditions for a function to remain nonnegative?
Let $f(x)=f'(0)x + f''(0)x^2/2+f'''(0)x^3/3!+…$ be the Taylor series expansion around $x=0$ of a nice, well-behaving function with offset term equal to zero.
I am looking for the conditions on the coefficients to guarantee that $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$.
(Originally, I had thought that all coefficients must be >=0, but a counter-example can be found rather easily: $f(x)=x-2x^2+x^3$)

not sure there is anything simple here as if you take any analytic function which is bounded on the positive axis, so $|g(x)| \le M, x \ge 0$ for which $g(0)=M$ (for example $\cos h(x), h(0)=0$ and any analytic $h$ or $e^{-h(x)}, h(0)=c, h(x) \ge c, x \ge 0$ will do) then trivially $M-g(x)$ will satisfy your condition

Solution for the special case of up to cubic terms:
If $x=0$, then $f(x)=0$.
If $x>0$, to have $f(x) \ge 0$, we have
$$f'(0)+f''(0)\frac{x}2+f'''(0)\frac{x^2}{6}\ge 0$$
We want the quadratic function to be non-negative over the positive domain.
Clearly, we need the quadratic function to be convex, otherwise, the quadratic curve would tend to negative infinity. Hence, we need $f'''(0) \ge 0$.
If $f'''(0)=0$, then we want $f"(0) + f''(0)\frac{x^2}2 \ge 0$. In that case, we would want the $y$-intercept and the slope to be nonnegative.
Now if $f'''(0)>0$, again, we want the intercept to be nonnegative, $f'(0)\ge 0$. The minimal point is attained when $f''(0)\frac12 + f'''(0)\frac{2x}{6}=0$, i.e. $x=-\frac{3f''(0)}{2f''''(0)}$
we consider two cases:

Case 1: The minimal point is non-positive. In that case, $f''(0)\le 0$.

Case 2: The minimal point is positive, in this case, we need the minimal value to attain a nonnegative value. That is when $f''(0) > 0$ and the discriminant is non-positive. $\frac{f''(0)^2}{4}-4f'(0)f'''(0)\frac{2}6 \le 0$. Or we can write it as $f''(0)^2 \le \frac{8}{3}f'(0)f'''(0)$



Summary: $f'(0) \ge 0$ and

$f'''(0)=0,  f''(0)\ge 0$,
$f'''(0)>0,   f''(0) \le 2\sqrt{\frac23f'(0)f'''(0)}$


Thanks for this in-depth answer.  However, there was a typo in my original question.  I am looking for the condition for an infinite series expansion.  My sincerest apologies.
